# Запись в БД oracle из KepServerEx v4

Tags: oracle, opc

Помогите разобраться как заставить opc писать в БД oracle, настройка конектора осуществлена по инструкции, но не понял где выбирать имя таблицы и имя поля, при выборе тега получаю ошибку: 
**Default User   Oracle Connectivity Suite   Failed to register MES item 'PPU.MTM11.Ch1' on connection 'TE' with the Oracle interface (ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:PLS-00201: identifier 'QA_DEVICE_PUB.ADD_DEVICE_INFO_BULK' must be declaredORA-06550: line 1, column 7:PL/SQL: Statement ignored).**
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Comment: А что такое `QA_DEVICE_PUB.ADD_DEVICE_INFO_BULK` видимо это какая то процедура или пакет. Видимо он должен быть создан и у подключающегося пользователя должны быть права на него

Comment: @mike дело в том что нигде ответа я не нашёл. И как решить проблему уже 3-й день не пойму.